# Good < ??? < Excellent

Tags: style

Please help me brag scientifically correct :-)

I made my master in Computer Science. Not even a reason to brag  weren't it for the fact that I made it aged 60 (good grief, I *swotted* for the exams - my insufferable 20 year old self would ROTFL about that). This is also the reason that "excellent notes" would be false: I managed an A grade only by that >< much. ("Excellent" in school notes is a flat 1.0 for me, I got 1.3.) On the other hand, "good notes" for me begins at "B", or 1.7.

So I'd like to hear a word inbetween "good" and "excellent", *especially* in the context of school notes. Obviously, I could simply rev up a [synonym finder](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/excellent) but I'd prefer to hear what a native speaker says about the results.

Comment: I would say 'I got my master's degree' and 'excellent marks'.

Comment: *No reason to brag **were it not** for the fact that...* OR ***...if it weren't** for the fact that...* Your contracted version is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious, and least ambiguous adjective between 'good' and 'excellent' would be '*very good*'.

There are so many synonyms of 'good' or 'excellent', and you may find resources where they are listed in supposed order of excellence, but they are not all in agreement and not all exhaustible lists. I would expect disagreements over the placing of a word like 'great', for example.

A common 'scale' for rating quality might be:

- Very Good
- Good
- Fair
- Poor
- Very Poor

There really is no right or wrong for such scales. On the subject of exam grades, you mentioned getting an 'A'. At one time that was the highest possible grade, but for some time in the UK there has existed an 'A+' (or A*) in some exam grading, as a way of recognising *exceptional* scores. These scales really are just made up.

Comment: THX, "very good" agreed with my instinct. (I'm not a native, but you don't speak and write English constantly throughout your whole life without learning *something* :-)